# What is the algorithm to find a suitable substitution for an integration by substitution?

Tags: integration, algorithms

I've noticed that Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica seems to be able to do integration by substitution. At first, it seems that It's using one of the algorithms like the algorithms to find antiderivatives (Risch, Hermite, Lazard, Atrobo, etc) but when I ask it to show step by step, it is actually able to find a suitable substituiton for an integration by substitution in some integrals.

I mentioned some algorithms to find antiderivatives and the possibility of existence of an algorithm that finds *suitable substitutions* but perhaps this algorithm actually depends on the algorithms I mentioned to find antiderivatives. Of this, I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps it find operations and the arguments, and differentiates all possible arguments to find if there is one that matches us for $u$-substitution.

Comment: You might want to look into open-source software such as Sage to see how such things are implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration algorithms usually use integral tables, integration rules and heuristics before applying Risch algorithm and its generalizations:
[Moses, J.: Symbolic integration the stormy decade. SYMSAC '71 Proceedings of the second ACM symposium on Symbolic and algebraic manipulation. 1971, 427-440](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.645.8977&rank=1)
[Terelius, B.: Symbolic Integration. Royal Institute of Technology, School of Computer Science and Communication, Stockholm, Sweden, 2009 chapter 2](https://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2009/rapporter09/terelius_bjorn_09095.pdf)

There are a number of integration rules, some of them with substitution. There are algorithms for checking the applicability of the integration rules:
[Find The Antiderivative of more complex expressions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112557/find-the-antiderivative-of-more-complex-expressions/3113046#3113046)