# Find The Antiderivative of more complex expressions.

Tags: calculus, integration

Need help finding the antiderivative of this one in particular

$\int_{}^{}$$\frac{dx}{3x²+1}$

Would you kindly also give some tips on how to find the antiderivative of any expressions. I am having problems switching from differential calculus to integral calculus as finding the antiderivative  is not as straight forward as finding the differential of an expression.

Comment: There are techniques of integration such as trigonometric substitutions

Comment: There is no algorithm for integration similar to differentiation. There are a lot of techniques you can learn, e.g. I found the following https://www.khanacademy.org/math/old-integral-calculus/integration-techniques

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Trigonometric_Substitution)  $\int\frac{dx}{x²+1}$ is calculated.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Comment: Use $u = \sqrt{3}x$ and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SIMPLY: By Formula**

You need to know the formula$$\int\frac1{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac1a\arctan\left(\frac xa\right)+c$$So your integral becomes:
$$\begin{align}\int \frac1{3x^2+1}dx&=\frac13\int\frac1{x^2+\frac13}dx=\frac13\int\frac1{x^2+\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)^2}dx\\&=\frac13\times\frac1{1/\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac x{1/\sqrt3}\right)+c\\&=\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\sqrt3x+c\end{align}$$

**ANOTHER METHOD: By Substitution**

Let $x=\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan \theta$. So $dx=\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt3}\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$. Also 
$$3x^2+1=3\left(\frac13\tan^2\theta\right)+1=\tan^2\theta+1=\sec^2\theta$$
Hence your integral becomes
$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{3x^2+1}dx&=\int\frac1{\sec^2\theta}\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\right)\\
&=\int\frac1{\sqrt3}d\theta\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt3}\theta +c\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdots(i)
\end{align}$$
Now since $x=\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\theta$, so $\theta=\arctan\sqrt3x$. Putting this in one we have the required answer as
$$\int\frac1{3x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan\sqrt3x+c$$

Answer (score 0):

Not all [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) have an elementary antiderivative: there are [nonelementary integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral).

Here are some usual integration rules:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Application_to_symbolic_integration
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions

Here are techniques for integration by parts:
Alcantara, E.: Integrals of composite functions through tabular integration by parts. Asia Pacific Higher Educ. Res. J. 2 (2015) (1)
Alcantara, E.: On the Derivation of Some Reduction Formula through Tabular Integration by Parts. Asia Pacific J. Multidisciplinary Res 3 (2015) (1) 80-84
Mardeli Jandja, M.; Lutfi, M.: The Five Columns Rule in Solving Definite Integration by Parts Through Transformation of Integral Limits. J. Phys.: Conf. Ser. 1028 (2018) 012109

Here are some integration rules that may be known not to everyone:
[Will, J.: Produktregel, Quotientenregel, Reziprokenregel, Kettenregel und Umkehrregel für die Integration. 2017](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316735230_Produktregel_Quotientenregel_Reziprokenregel_Kettenregel_und_Umkehrregel_fur_die_Integration)
[Will, J.: Product rule, quotient rule, reciprocal rule, chain rule and inverse rule for integration. May 2017](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340741699_Product_rule_quotient_rule_reciprocal_rule_chain_rule_and_inverse_rule_for_integration)
Maybe these integration rules are not taught everywhere. They are deduced from the usual general integration rules above.

Here is a hierarchy for applying integration rules and integration methods:
[Swartz, J.: Symbolic integration using CLIPS. Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/symbolic-integration-using-clips/184410219)

Answer (score 0):

Generalize this. Start with the integral$$I=\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{a^2+(bx)^2}$$Let $z=\tfrac {bx}a$ so that $\mathrm dz=\tfrac ba\,\mathrm dx$. Thus$$\begin{align*}I & =\frac ab\int\frac {\mathrm dz}{a^2+a^2z^2}\\ & =\frac 1{ab}\int\frac {\mathrm dz}{1+z^2}\end{align*}$$The integral is now easily seen to be $\arctan z+C$. Thus$$\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{a^2+(bx)^2}\color{blue}{=\frac 1{ab}\arctan\left(\frac {bx}a\right)+C}$$Now set $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt3$.